# "analog out of range 92.6kHz / 58Hz" message  - unable to boot to desktop

Tags: boot

I am not a pro on using Ubuntu. However, I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04. My PC already had Windows 7 Ultimate and through Wubi I installed Ubuntu 12.04.

When I start my PC, I get Windows Boot Manager and it gives me options: Windows 7 and Ubuntu. So, when I used to select Ubuntu, it was booting to desktop. Whenever I selected Ubuntu, I used to get `Analog out of range 92.6kHz / 58Hz`.and it stayed for 3-4 seconds and then it used to boot to desktop. However, there was some display driver issue because of which I could feel slowness. I could access both Ubuntu Unity and Ubuntu 2d. However, there did not seem any difference between the two. The same kind of slowness I could feel in both.

So, there was some startup option and I disabled Nvidia because I thought this was causing the problem. However, after that when I restarted Ubuntu again, I only get the `Analog out of range 92.6kHz/58Hz` screen and it stays there forever and does not boot to Ubuntu.

Guys, plz help!

Answer (score 1):

Prepare a live usb or use the ubuntu live cd if you have. Boot through it.

1. Install and Run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) (for Installation instruction follow the link)
2. Click `Advanced options`
3. Go to the `GRUB options` tab
4. Tick the `out-of-range` option
5. Apply

Now reboot your system.

For slowness of drivers of nvidia, install nvidia from x-updates ppa. (I am guessing you don't have an optimus laptop)

Connect to internet,Open a terminal and issue following commands,

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I booted my system with Boot Repair, I can see that Grub locations and Grub Options tabs grayed out. Would you please suggest me more.

Comment: That means that Boot-Repair can't find any GRUB files (grub-install / grub-update). Please click the `Create BootInfo` button and indicate the URL that will appear.

Comment: Hi there, here is the 'Create BootInfo' link - http://paste.ubuntu.com/1104483/

On AskUbuntu, is there anyway, I can send a private message to a user because I am unable to see such a feature when i visit another's profile.

Comment: Guys, I am still stuck up on that issue.. plz help!!!

Comment: retry after a `recommended repair`

Comment: still does not seem to work